# Hide Data Series on Google Chart by Clicking Legend

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to modify some code provided in an answer to a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010311/show-hide-toggle-data-series-on-google-chart-by-clicking-legend/72015143?noredirect=1#comment130203411_72015143).  The code shows or hides a data series on a Google Chart by clicking it's representation in the legend.  The problem I have is that the series disappears as expected when you click on the legend to hide it, but when you then change the date(s) using the date slider above the chart, the hidden series then reappears albeit greyed out.  I want a hidden series to stay invisible when the date(s) are changed and not reappear greyed out.

Code copied from the above answer is as follows:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['controls']}).then(initialize);

function initialize() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1001YnF8LCwKyzpS4pgmZnwFVigL-LlnqwWn6xjnso2k/edit#gid=0&range=A:BT');
      query.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response) {

    var data = response.getDataTable();
    //Asign units of 'mm' to data.
    var formatMS = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '# mm'});

    // format data into mm.
    for (var colIndex = 1; colIndex < data.getNumberOfColumns(); colIndex++) {formatMS.format(data, colIndex);}
    var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    dataView.setColumns([0,1,2,{sourceColumn: 3, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 4, role: 'interval'}, 5,{sourceColumn: 6, 'type': 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}},7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,{sourceColumn: 16, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 17, role: 'interval'}, 18,{sourceColumn: 19, 'type': 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}},20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,{sourceColumn: 29, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 30, role: 'interval'},31,{sourceColumn: 32, 'type': 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}},33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,{sourceColumn: 42, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 43, role: 'interval'}, 44,{sourceColumn: 45, 'type': 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}},46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,{sourceColumn: 55, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 56, role: 'interval'}, 57,{sourceColumn: 58, 'type': 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}},59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71]);
    var viewColumns = [0,7,20,33,46,59,66,67,68,69,70,71];

    var YearPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
      containerId: 'filter_div',
      options: {
        maxValue: 2150,
        minValue: 1891,
        filterColumnLabel: 'Year',
        ui: {
          cssClass: 'filter-date',
          format: {pattern: '0000'},
          labelStacking: 'vertical',
          allowTyping: true,
          allowMultiple: false
        }
      },
      state: {lowValue: 1891, highValue: 2150},
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(YearPicker, 'statechange', function () {
      var state = YearPicker.getState();
      state.lowValue = Math.min(2021, state.lowValue);
      YearPicker.setState({
        lowValue: state.lowValue,
        highValue: state.highValue
      });
      YearPicker.draw();
    });

    var series = {
      0: {color:'navy', visibleInLegend: true}, //Auckland
      1: {color:'green', visibleInLegend: true }, //Taranaki
      2: {color:'gold', visibleInLegend: true}, //Wellington
      3: {color:'red', visibleInLegend: true}, //Lyttelton
      4: {color:'DeepSkyBlue', visibleInLegend: true}, //Dunedin
      5: {color:'#47d045', visibleInLegend: true}, //NZ RCP2.6 M
      6: {color:'#0e038d', visibleInLegend: true}, //NZ RCP4.5 M
      7: {color:'#b8bb62', visibleInLegend: true}, //NZ RCP8.5 M
      8: {color:'#b22123', visibleInLegend: true}, //NZ RCP8.5 H
      9: {color:'blue', visibleInLegend: true}, //NZ Mean
      10: {color:'blue', visibleInLegend: false}, //NZ Mean
    };

    // save series colors
    var seriesColors = {};
    for (var column in series) {
      if (series.hasOwnProperty(column)) {
        seriesColors[column] = series[column].color;
      }
    }


    var MSLChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      containerId: 'chart_div',
      dataTable: dataView,
      options: {
        fontSize: '20',
        title: 'NZ Annual Relative Mean Sea Level Summary',
        hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: '0000'},
        vAxis: {title: 'Height above 1986-2005 IPCC Baseline (mm)', format:'###0'},
        height: 600,
        chartArea: {height: '81%', width: '85%', left: 100},
        legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 5, alignment: 'start', textStyle: {fontSize: 9}},
        colors: ['blue'],
        tooltip: {
          isHtml: true
        },
        trendlines: {
          9: {
            type: 'linear',
            color: 'black',
            visibleInLegend: true,
            showR2: true,
          },
          10: {
            type: 'polynomial',
            color: 'purple',
            degree: 2,
            visibleInLegend: true,
            showR2: true,
          },
        },
        series: series,
        intervals: { 'style':'bars','color': '#6292dc' },
        interpolateNulls: 'True',
      },
      view: {columns: viewColumns}
    });

    var columns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataView.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      columns.push(i);
    }
    google.visualization.events.addListener(MSLChart, 'select', function () {
      var chartArea = MSLChart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface().getChartAreaBoundingBox();
      var vAxisTop = MSLChart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface().getVAxisValue(chartArea.top);
      var vAxisBtm = MSLChart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface().getVAxisValue(chartArea.top + chartArea.height);

      var sel = MSLChart.getChart().getSelection();

      // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
      if (sel.length > 0) {
         // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
         if ((sel[0].row === null) && (sel[0].column > 0)) {
             // get actual column number from view
             var col = viewColumns[sel[0].column];
             if (columns[col] == col) {
                // hide the data series
                columns[col] = {
                   label: dataView.getColumnLabel(col),
                   type: dataView.getColumnType(col),
                   calc: function () {
                      return null;
                   }
                };

                // grey out the legend entry
                series[sel[0].column - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
            } else {
                // show the data series
                columns[col] = col;
                series[sel[0].column - 1].color = seriesColors[sel[0].column - 1];
            }

            // set new view columns
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataView);
            view.setColumns(columns);
            MSLChart.setDataTable(view);

            // prevent y-axis from changing when series is removed
            MSLChart.setOption('series', series);
            MSLChart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max', vAxisTop);
            MSLChart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', vAxisBtm);

            // re-draw chart
            MSLChart.draw();
         }
      }
    });

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div')).bind(YearPicker, MSLChart).draw(dataView);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is with the dashboard.
when the slider is used, the dashboard re-draws the chart with the original data view,
which includes the column values for all series.
but the chart keeps the previous options, which is why the series is greyed out.

you will need lose the dashboard and draw the chart and slider independently.

which also means you will need to manually filter the data based on the state of the slider.

but doing so raises a few issues.

you will need to maintain the chart selection outside of the function to handle the series toggle.

and you will need to use a data table instead of a data view as the main source of data.
otherwise, you will lose the original rows when you filter the data view.

following is what I came up with to keep everything in sync.

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['controls']}).then(initialize);

function initialize() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1001YnF8LCwKyzpS4pgmZnwFVigL-LlnqwWn6xjnso2k/edit#gid=0&range=A:BT');
      query.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response) {

    var data = response.getDataTable();
    //Asign units of 'mm' to data.
    var formatMS = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '# mm'});

    // format data into mm.
    for (var colIndex = 1; colIndex < data.getNumberOfColumns(); colIndex++) {formatMS.format(data, colIndex);}
    var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    dataView.setColumns([0,1,2,{sourceColumn: 3, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 4, role: 'interval'}, 5,{sourceColumn: 6, 'type': 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}},7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,{sourceColumn: 16, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 17, role: 'interval'}, 18,{sourceColumn: 19, 'type': 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}},20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,{sourceColumn: 29, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 30, role: 'interval'},31,{sourceColumn: 32, 'type': 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}},33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,{sourceColumn: 42, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 43, role: 'interval'}, 44,{sourceColumn: 45, 'type': 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}},46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,{sourceColumn: 55, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 56, role: 'interval'}, 57,{sourceColumn: 58, 'type': 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}},59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71]);
    var viewColumns = [0,7,20,33,46,59,66,67,68,69,70,71];

    // use data table as main source of data
    dataView = dataView.toDataTable();

    var YearPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
      containerId: 'filter_div',
      dataTable: dataView,  // <-- add data table here in order to draw independently
      options: {
        maxValue: 2150,
        minValue: 1891,
        filterColumnLabel: 'Year',
        ui: {
          cssClass: 'filter-date',
          format: {pattern: '0000'},
          labelStacking: 'vertical',
          allowTyping: true,
          allowMultiple: false
        }
      },
      state: {lowValue: 1891, highValue: 2150},
    });

    var series = {
      0: {color:'navy', visibleInLegend: true}, //Auckland
      1: {color:'green', visibleInLegend: true }, //Taranaki
      2: {color:'gold', visibleInLegend: true}, //Wellington
      3: {color:'red', visibleInLegend: true}, //Lyttelton
      4: {color:'DeepSkyBlue', visibleInLegend: true}, //Dunedin
      5: {color:'#47d045', visibleInLegend: true}, //NZ RCP2.6 M
      6: {color:'#0e038d', visibleInLegend: true}, //NZ RCP4.5 M
      7: {color:'#b8bb62', visibleInLegend: true}, //NZ RCP8.5 M
      8: {color:'#b22123', visibleInLegend: true}, //NZ RCP8.5 H
      9: {color:'blue', visibleInLegend: true}, //NZ Mean
      10: {color:'blue', visibleInLegend: false}, //NZ Mean
    };

    // save series colors
    var seriesColors = {};
    for (var column in series) {
      if (series.hasOwnProperty(column)) {
        seriesColors[column] = series[column].color;
      }
    }

    var MSLChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      containerId: 'chart_div',
      dataTable: dataView,
      options: {
        fontSize: '20',
        title: 'NZ Annual Relative Mean Sea Level Summary',
        hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: '0000'},
        vAxis: {title: 'Height above 1986-2005 IPCC Baseline (mm)', format:'###0'},
        height: 600,
        chartArea: {height: '81%', width: '85%', left: 100},
        legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 5, alignment: 'start', textStyle: {fontSize: 9}},
        colors: ['blue'],
        tooltip: {
          isHtml: true
        },
        trendlines: {
          9: {
            type: 'linear',
            color: 'black',
            visibleInLegend: true,
            showR2: true,
          },
          10: {
            type: 'polynomial',
            color: 'purple',
            degree: 2,
            visibleInLegend: true,
            showR2: true,
          },
        },
        series: series,
        intervals: { 'style':'bars','color': '#6292dc' },
        interpolateNulls: 'True',
      },
      view: {columns: viewColumns}
    });

    // save selection outside of toggle series function
    var sel;

    var columns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataView.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      columns.push(i);
    }

    // use named function for statechange to also be called from select event
    google.visualization.events.addListener(YearPicker, 'statechange', onState);

    // select event
    google.visualization.events.addListener(MSLChart, 'select', function () {
      // save selection
      sel = MSLChart.getChart().getSelection();

      // call state change to display correct rows
      onState(true);  // <-- true argument to trigger series toggle
    });

    // handle state change on slider
    function onState(toggleColumns) {
      var state = YearPicker.getState();
      state.lowValue = Math.min(2021, state.lowValue);
      YearPicker.setState({
        lowValue: state.lowValue,
        highValue: state.highValue
      });
      YearPicker.draw();

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataView);
      var rows = dataView.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 0,
        minValue: state.lowValue,
        maxValue: state.highValue
      }]);
      view.setRows(rows);
      redrawChart(view, (toggleColumns === true));  // <-- we only want to toggle series if called from select event
    }

    // toggle series
    function redrawChart(view, toggleColumns) {
      var chartArea = MSLChart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface().getChartAreaBoundingBox();
      var vAxisTop = MSLChart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface().getVAxisValue(chartArea.top);
      var vAxisBtm = MSLChart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface().getVAxisValue(chartArea.top + chartArea.height);

      // toggle columns?
      if (toggleColumns) {
        // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
        if (sel.length > 0) {
           // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
           if ((sel[0].row === null) && (sel[0].column > 0)) {
               // get actual column number from view
               var col = viewColumns[sel[0].column];
               if (columns[col] == col) {
                  // hide the data series
                  columns[col] = {
                     label: dataView.getColumnLabel(col),
                     type: dataView.getColumnType(col),
                     calc: function () {
                        return null;
                     }
                  };

                  // grey out the legend entry
                  series[sel[0].column - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
              } else {
                  // show the data series
                  columns[col] = col;
                  series[sel[0].column - 1].color = seriesColors[sel[0].column - 1];
              }

           }
        }
      }

      // set new view columns
      view.setColumns(columns);
      MSLChart.setDataTable(view);

      // prevent y-axis from changing when series is removed
      MSLChart.setOption('series', series);
      MSLChart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max', vAxisTop);
      MSLChart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', vAxisBtm);

      // re-draw chart
      MSLChart.draw();
    }

    // draw slider and chart initially
    YearPicker.draw();
    MSLChart.draw();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat.  I've been tearing my hair our with this since you answered the original question above.  Would never have come up with the above solution in a million years.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since they're greyed out, maybe you could add a for-loop in the date slider's listener to go through all the series and hide the ones with *color='#CCCCCC'* again. Maybe re-drawing after changing the dates reset the visibilities.